# Cocoa: get the URL from webview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to Mac programming. I want to block some URLs in a webview. I have placed a webview and am opening a specific URL in it. When the user clicks on some links I want to check (by getting the URL) the URL. I want to know from which delegate function I can get the current URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the policyDelegate property and then implement this method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener {
  NSInteger actionType = [[actionInformation valueForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] integerValue];
  if( actionType == WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    NSURL *url = [actionInformation valueForKey: WebActionOriginalURLKey];
    if ( !url) {
      url = request.URL;
    }
    if ( YES) { // your custom check
      [listener use];
    } else {
      [listener ignore];
    }
  } else {
    [listener use];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the url in webViewDidFinishLoad: delegate method. You can get the url from webview like below

```
webView.request.URL
```